# Fixing text in a .txt file

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I've got a homework assignment that I have no idea how to even start. The instructions are to have an input .txt file with text that contains some mistakes. I have to fix that in the output .txt file, meaning, only 1 space between words, no space before a comma/punctuation and exactly 1 space after those. Capital letters at the beginning of a sentence. It also says that I don't have to use the ASCII table, because of the fact the capital letters are coded before lower case letters?

Input text example:

```
jaMEs  ,  mY  neIgHBor  , Is  A  dOcTor . he SPoke eaSIlY  ,  CLEarly And eloQuENtly.
```

Output:

```
James, my neighbor, is a doctor. He spoke easily, clearly and eloquently.
```

All we did in class was go over ifstream/ofstream and inputing/changing data in a .txt file, so I have no idea where to even begin. Is there a way to solve it, so it fixes any incorrect input text, or do I have to manually change every mistake in this particular text? No need to solve it for me. An example or some tips to get me started would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1) SO is not a tutorial service either. Did you try asking your tutor for help? 2) "_All we did in class was go over ifstream/ofstream and inputing/changing data in a .txt file_" And this is is _exactly_ what you need here, so what's the problem?

Comment: Start trying to come up with a solution. Write some code to get the file in and write it out unchanged. Then stick in a function to make a change. Expand that function. Develop it. If you get stuck with a specific issue in the code, then come back and ask. But this is not a place to get your homework done for you.

Comment: Read the file. Check for each character if it's a punctuation, whitespace or a letter. If it's a letter, do ... If it's a whitespace, do ...

Answer (score 1):

Break the problem into pieces. First, read in the data from a file. Store it however you want, probably a string, then move on to the next part. Check each character and see if it is correct. If it is, move on. If not, make it correct and then move on. When you hit the end of the input, you are done.
To check if a character is correct, you just need to check if it is and should be lower case and if it should be a character. If it should be and isn't, fix it, otherwise move on.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect each character as you read it.  If it's a full-stop, then remember to upcase the next alphanumeric, otherwise to downcase it.  If it's a space, then just remember that you've seen a space - don't print it until you see a word character.

Something like:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    int(*t)(int) = std::toupper;
    char const*last = "";
    std::for_each(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{std::cin},
                  std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{},
                  [&](char c){if(std::isspace(c))last=" ";
                      else if(std::isalnum(c=t(c)))std::cout<<last<<c,last="",t=std::tolower;
                      else if(c==',')std::cout<<c,last=" ";
                      else if(c=='.')std::cout<<c,last=" ",t=std::toupper;});
}
```